# Snowflake stored procedure error , I want to create a procedure that calls an existing procedure and then with it's results join to other tables etc

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace procedure sp_sp1_2

(TABLENAME varchar(60), ID varchar(60), DATE varchar(60), VARIABLE varchar(60))

RETURNS TABLE ()

LANGUAGE SQL

AS

DECLARE

res resultset DEFAULT

(

CALL sp_sp1 (:TABLENAME, :ID, :DATE, :VARIABLE) 

CREATE OR REPLACE temp TABLE a1 AS

SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))

SELECT * FROM a1 JOIN a2 ON a1.id = a2.id

);

BEGIN

RETURN table(res);

END;
```

This stored procedure returns without error outside the stored procedure:

```
CALL sp_sp1 (:TABLENAME, :ID, :DATE, :VARIABLE);
CREATE OR REPLACE temp TABLE a1 AS
SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
SELECT * FROM a1 JOIN a2 ON a1.id = a2.id;
```

If this statement by itself is in the stored procedure it returns without error:

```
CALL sp_sp1 (:TABLENAME, :ID, :DATE, :VARIABLE)
```

but when I also with to add these other statements, the stored procedure throws an error.

Coming from T-SQL so this snowflake SQL stored procedure logic is still puzzling me.

Comment: Hi - I’m not sure what all that code is meant to be after res is defined but you’re still in the declaration section so none of it is valid. Even if it was in the main BEGIN…END section it’s almost certainly not going to do what you want. What does the sp_sp1 proc do and what are you attempting to do widen querying table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) ?

Comment: sp_sp1  returns various statistics about a variable, we would like to take the results of that to join to other tables to get additional data. This executes fine on it's own:
create or replace procedure sp_sp1_2

(TABLENAME varchar(60), ID varchar(60), DATE varchar(60), VARIABLE varchar(60))

RETURNS TABLE ()

LANGUAGE SQL

AS

DECLARE

res resultset DEFAULT

(

CALL sp_sp1 (:TABLENAME, :ID, :DATE, :VARIABLE) 
);

BEGIN

RETURN table(res);

END; 
but ideally we want to add additional info from other tables inside sp_sp1_2 as well

Comment: You probably need to start by reading the documentation for using resultsets e.g. you need a cursor to process the data in the resultset: https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey lets create all the things it seems are missing from the question, in simple example forms:

```
create or replace table a1 (id number, val text);
create or replace table a2 (id number);
insert into a2 values 
    (1),(2),(3);

create or replace procedure sp_sp1(TABLENAME varchar(60), ID varchar(60), DATE varchar(60), VARIABLE varchar(60))
returns TABLE(id number, val text)
LANGUAGE SQL AS 
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET DEFAULT (SELECT seq8() as id, :TABLENAME as val FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount=>10)));

BEGIN
    return TABLE(res);
END;
```

```
CALL sp_sp1('aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
```

| ID | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | aaa |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | aaa |
| 3 | aaa |
| 4 | aaa |
| 5 | aaa |
| 6 | aaa |
| 7 | aaa |
| 8 | aaa |
| 9 | aaa |

righto, so we now, can run the SQL that works by itself, I dropped the TEMP of the table, just to make it all simpler, will try add back in later:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE a1 AS
  SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

all good

```
SELECT * FROM a1 JOIN a2 ON a1.id = a2.id;
```

| ID | VAL | ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 |
| 2 | aaa | 2 |
| 3 | aaa | 3 |

Right, we are ready to start...

So you have three statements, inside your "result set" and a resultset is just one set of results, so I am going to assume you want the final results, so will move some tihngs around:

```
create or replace procedure sp_sp1_2
    (TABLENAME varchar(60), ID varchar(60), DATE varchar(60), VARIABLE varchar(60))
    RETURNS TABLE ()
    LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
DECLARE
    res resultset;
BEGIN
    CALL sp_sp1 (:TABLENAME, :ID, :DATE, :VARIABLE);

    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE a1 AS
        SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

    res := (SELECT * FROM a1 JOIN a2 ON a1.id = a2.id);

    RETURN table(res);
END;
```

```
CALL sp_sp1_2('xxx', 'bb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
```

and this gives:

| ID | VAL | ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | 1 |
| 2 | xxx | 2 |
| 3 | xxx | 3 |